# PHP / MySQL sort item first if "word" is present, then the rest ASC?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a food database and I'm trying to implement a simple search that would put first items that are "raw" or "least processed".

For example, when I'm searching for "carrot", I really don't want to have to sort through all the processed food (carrot cake, etc), fast food (Wendy's carrot big mac, etc). I want the first items to be "carrots, raw", "carrot, boiled", "carrot frozen", "carrot, canned", etc.

Is there a way to do that in MYSQL so that I sort my items by "presence of keyword" first (let's say : "raw", "fresh", "boiled", "frozen"...) and then all other occurrences after?

Note :

- the keyword may or may not be present
- the keyword may be anywhere
- I must also find the search keyword alone, in this example "carrot" so that "carrot cake" is still in my results.

Thanks a lot!

Joel

Comment: Show code for what you have tried.

Comment: I'm doing right now 5 queries and merging the resulting arrays in PHP. I'm looking for a more efficient and cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM foods
WHERE foods.title LIKE '%carrot%'
ORDER BY foods.title LIKE '%raw%' DESC, foods.title
```

The reason it's `DESC` is because that will return 0 or 1, and you want the results that returned 1 to be sorted first.

Comment: Wow! it took you 2 min to make my day! Thanks a bunch, it's absolutely fantastic! Just to add something, because I had multiple keywords, I changed the query to this : `select * from FOOD where L_FD_NME LIKE '%carrot%' order by  L_FD_NME LIKE '%raw%' or L_FD_NME LIKE '%fresh%' or L_FD_NME LIKE '%frozen%'  or L_FD_NME LIKE '%boiled%'  or L_FD_NME LIKE '%cooked%'  or L_FD_NME LIKE '%canned%' desc, FAV desc, L_FD_NME asc limit 200`. I had no clue you could do that :)

Comment: One problem with these kind of query is that they are difficult to index. so if the records get too big, its hard to optimise.

Answer (score 1):

A natural word search returns records in order according to relevancy, so if you added a FULLTEXT index to the foods.title column, you could simply perform a search like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM foods
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('carrot raw fresh frozen canned')
  AND title LIKE 'carrot%'
```

The additional LIKE criteria filters out results that don't have the word carrot at the beginning like 'fish, canned'.

FULLTEXT indexes can only be used with MyISAM tables currently, though soon (v5.6+) you can use them with InnoDB also.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have and additional field called "processed" that stores a 1 if the food is processed. then just sort by processed and name.

Comment: Because there are 10 000 items and I don't want to spend my week sorting them ;)

Comment: Well you could do a update table set processed =1 where name like '%raw%'.